# Использование std::string в dll

Tags: c++, строки, dll, visual-studio-2015

Доброго времени суток.
Изучая dll, получил интересное задание - сделать библиотеку, работающую с std::string и сделать 2 exe, юзающих dll, одна из которых будет работать нормально, а другая некорректно.
Корректная передача строки из dll в exe получилась довольно просто. Вот код:

#### dll

//dll_and_string.h

```
#pragma once  

#ifdef DLL_AND_STRING_EXPORTS  
#define DLL_AND_STRING_EXPORTS_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define DLL_AND_STRING_EXPORTS_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif  

#include <string>

extern "C++"
{    
    DLL_AND_STRING_EXPORTS_API std::string hi();
}
```

// MathLibrary.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application

```
// Compile by using: cl /EHsc /DMATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS /LD MathLibrary.cpp  

//#include "stdafx.h"  
#include "dll_and_string.h"  

std::string hi()
{
    return "hi, baby!";
}
```

//dll_and_string.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

#### exe

//client.cpp

```
#include <iostream>  
#include "dll_and_string.h"  

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << hi() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Как будет выглядеть кейс, при котором строка из dll прочитается некорректно? Или хотя бы в каком направлении копать?

Comment: Бинарная несовместимость может всё сломать

Comment: Что такое кейс?

Comment: кейс(case-англ)-ситуация, случай, пример, вариант

Comment: Попробуйте скомпилоровать dll другим компилятором

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашлось, выкладываю
При сборке использовал разный тулсет - в моем примере это был 140 для exe и 120_xp для dll
в результате передача данных через const char * проходила норм, через std::string приложение падало.

#### dll

//dll_and_string.h

```
#pragma once  

#ifdef DLL_AND_STRING_EXPORTS  
#define DLL_AND_STRING_EXPORTS_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define DLL_AND_STRING_EXPORTS_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif  

#include <string>

extern "C++"
{    
    DLL_AND_STRING_EXPORTS_API std::string func1(std::string text);
    DLL_AND_STRING_EXPORTS_API const char *func2(const char *text);
}
```

//dll_and_string.cpp

```
#include "dll_and_string.h"  

std::string func1(std::string text)
{
    static std::string text_to_return = text.c_str();
    return text_to_return;
}

const char *func2(const char *text)
{
    static std::string text_to_return = text;
    return text_to_return.c_str();
}
```

//dll_main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

#### exe

//client.cpp

```
#include <iostream>  
#include "dll_and_string.h"  

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << func1("hello, world!") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```